# Aggregation in macroeconomic model with expanding product varieties

Tags: macroeconomics, economic-growth, aggregate-production

The final good is produced by a competitive industry combining a set of intermediate
products, $i ∈ [0, N_t ]$ , using a CES aggregator:

\begin{equation}
Y= \left( \int_{0}^{N_t} y(i)^{\frac{\sigma -1}{\sigma}} di \right)^{\frac{\sigma}{\sigma -1}}
\end{equation}

The intermediate $y(i)$ is produced in monopolistic competition accoring to the following technology

$y(i)=[l(i)^{\frac{\epsilon - 1}{\epsilon}} +\alpha(i)(\tilde{\gamma}x(i))^{\frac{\epsilon - 1}{\epsilon}}]^{\frac{\epsilon \beta}{\epsilon-1}}h(i)^{1-\beta}$

$\beta \in (0,1)$, $\tilde{\gamma}$ is a productivity parameter, and $\epsilon$>1 is the EOS between low-skilled workers,$l(i)$, and machines $x(i)$. Also, $\alpha(i)$ is an indicator function taking value one if the product $i$ is automated and zero otherwise. Mathematically, $\alpha(i) \in \{0,1\}$. Finally, $h(i)$ are high-skilled workers.
Finally, $G$ denotes the share of automated firms
[image]

$\textbf{How to get the aggregate equation for the final output?}$